# I need some help with the derivative of this function.

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

Hey guys i was wondering , what is the derivative function of this function.

f(x) = $\sqrt{x} - e^{-x}$

Any advise will be greated.

Comment: have you tried with definition?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried? This context is important for people to be able to write answers that are appropriate to your question.

Comment: I thought i can do it something with that e^-x , but it seems that its derivative is the same .  so we just derivate the $/sqrt(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^n) = nx^{n-1}$$ and $$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{ax}) = ae^{ax}.$$  Observing that $$f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{2}} - e^{-x}$$ we apply these general results to find that $$f'(x) = \frac {1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}+e^{-x}$$

Comment: Thank you , that was so simple .

Comment: please do not answer questions without considerable effort... please do not think otherwise...

Comment: No problems Nicholas. Sorry, I was in a rush @Praphulla Koushik. Do you think my edited anwer constitutes sufficient effort?

Comment: excuse me... I did not meant that your answer is not worthy i meant that the question do not show any effort so, you better not answer such questions until the person who asked question show his own effort in solving the problem...

Comment: Oh I see. I'm not breaking any of the sites rules by answering questions even when insufficient effort is demonstrated though am I?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\sqrt{x} -e^{-x}$
Let $p(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ it is true, that $p'(x)=g'(x)+h'(x)$ so we can write, that:
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x)'&=&(\sqrt{x})'+(-e^{-x})'\\
(\sqrt{x})'&=&(x^{\frac{1}{2}})'=\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\\
(-e^{-x})'&=&-1*(e^{-x})'=-1*e^{-x}*(-x)'=-1*e^{-x}*-1=e^{-x}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now sum it up and we get, that:
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+e^{-x}$$